# Remove reference to raster layer object PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, layers

I am developing a **plugin** to load a set of raster files on QGIS. When there is a large number of files to be loaded, the main UI freezes. So I use `QgsTask` to move the creation of raster layers to a thread. This thread then returns a list of raster layer objects. I was able to load these layers on QGIS.

When I remove the layers from canvas by using QGIS UI or `QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers()`, the layers are removed. However, it seems that the raster layer objects still exist. I cannot move or remove the source raster files on disk. It says that the files are still being used by `qgis.bin`. This did not happen when I did not use the thread.

Here is my code:

Create raster layers task:

```
task = QgsTask.fromFunction('Load images', createRasterLayers, params = [result["files"]], on_finished=self.load_layers)
task.progressChanged.connect(lambda: self.dlg.he_progress.setValue(task.progress()))
task.taskTerminated.connect(lambda: self.dlg.he_progress.reset())
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)
```

The function that creates a list of raster layers, but not load yet:

```
def createRasterLayers(task, params):
            
    # extract parameters
    images = params[0]
                
    n_photos = len(images)
    
    # set task progress
    task.setProgress(1)
    
    # then reload the photos 
    count = 0
    n_processed = 0
    rlayers = list()
    rt = QgsRasterTransparency()
    rt.initializeTransparentPixelList(0,0,0)
    for img in images:
        fileInfo = QFileInfo(img)
        path = fileInfo.filePath()
        basename = fileInfo.baseName()
        r = QgsRasterLayer(path, basename)
        crs = r.crs()
        crs.createFromId(4326)
        r.setCrs(crs)
        # set transparent for the image
        r.renderer().setRasterTransparency(rt) 
        
        if r.isValid():
            rlayers.append(r)
            count = count + 1
        
        # set progress
        n_processed = n_processed + 1
        percent = float(n_processed/n_photos) * 100
        task.setProgress(percent)
        
        if task.isCanceled():
            raise Exception('Task canceled!')
            
    return {'rlayers': rlayers, 'task': task.description()}
```

And finally, the function that loads the layers on map:

```
def load_layers(self, exception, result=None):
        
    if exception is None:
        for r in result['rlayers']:
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(r, addToLegend=True)
```

Comment: It appears to me the rlayers variable, and thus `result['rlayers']`, will hold references to the layer. What's the scope of the `result` variable you use in load_layers? What's in there after you removed a layer from the qgis map?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the QgsRasterLayer to the Core Thread.

```
if r.isValid():
    r.moveToThread(QCoreApplication.instance().thread())
    rlayers.append(r)
    count = count + 1
```

I had issues with QgsVectorLayers loading from QgsTask and that helped.